# How to delimit the bounds of a histogram with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I can't change the boundary of my bars in a histogram. By default, the bars are aligned with the numbers on the x-axis but I would rather have the numbers be the bounds than centred. For example: start the bar at 0 to 5, from 5 to 10, etc. Is this possible?

My R code:
`ggplot(data, aes(x=Min_Pre))+ geom_histogram(color="white", aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count))),binwidth=5)+scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+scale_x_continuous(n.breaks=10, limits = c(0, 50))`

[Histogram of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk0gh.png)

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve your desired resulting by setting `boundary=0` in `geom_histogram`.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame(
  Min_Pre = rnorm(100, 25, 10)
)

ggplot(data, aes(x = Min_Pre)) +
  geom_histogram(boundary = 0, color = "white", aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count))), binwidth = 5) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10, limits = c(0, 50))
```

[image]